# Verify a method call happening in a separate thread/thread pool using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have successfully setup and verified methods with Moq before but somehow I can't get this to work. I tried various answers on the same exception without luck.

I have implemented observer pattern, so I'm mocking `IObserver<T>`:

```
var mock = new Mock<IObserver<T>>();
mock.Setup(s => s.OnCompleted());
```

Here the `OnCompleted()` looks something like

```
public void OnCompleted()
{
}
```

Now in the test, using the `mock`, I do like this:

```
// observable is the SUT.
var unsubscriber = observable.Subscribe(mock.Object);
// Cause OnCompleted() to be called: I verified that there's one observer in the observers list in observable and that my break point is correctly hit.

mock.Verify(v => v.OnCompleted(), Times.AtLeastOnce);
unsubscriber.Dispose();
```

I get the following error:

```
Message: Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: v => v.OnCompleted()

Configured setups: 
IObserver<T> s => s.OnCompleted()
No invocations performed.
```

EDIT: SUT Code

SUT is a class initialized a using a factory method. I will summarize the relevant parts here:

There's an initializer method:

```
public void InitializeMyClass()
{
   for(var i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
   {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Proc())
   }

   this.timer = new Timer(CheckStatus, null, 0, 1000);
}
```

`CheckStatus` method checks if the workloads in threads started in `Initializer` reaches a specific status and raises the event indicating completion:

```
private void CheckStatus(object status)
{
   // Inspect all background threads.
   // This is simply done by observing a set of values in a concurrent dict<int, bool>.:

   if (!this.concurrentDict.Values.Any(a => a))
   {
       this.NotifyObservers();
       this.timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
   }
}
```

`NotifyObservers()` calls the `OnCompleted()` method:

```
private void NotifyObservers()
{
    foreach(o in observers)
    {
        o.OnCompleted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your verify would fail since that `OnCompleted()` would never get called in test scenario

Comment: @Rahul, can you explain a bit? Because, during debug, I can see `observable` calls `OnCompleted()`. What do you mean it never gets called?

Comment: @swdon try setup it with callback like `mock.Setup(...).Callback(() => put breakpoint here)` and you will see did it actually called

Comment: @AleksAndreev Thanks a lot for the suggestion. That was awesome! So, the break point in the call back is hit. But the test still shows 0 count...

Comment: @swdon Can't [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EDypb). It does not work on netfiddle but on my local machine it just print `actually called` without any exceptions. Does my example work on your machine?

Comment: @Aleks Andreev That's the thing. It gets called correctly on my machine too. I just don't understand why it doesn't register as a call in Moq.

Comment: Could you share the sut code?

Comment: @swdon we're going to need to see the sut code and how it invokes the mocked dependency member.

Comment: @Johnny Added the SUT code.

Comment: @swdon While the added code snippets shed some light on the problem you need to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Otherwise we are left guess what other code that may have been omitted might be causing problems.

Comment: This could very well be a threading issue or the timer might not have invoked by the time the verification was done. Which means that the mock members were not called. You might have to wait a bit. But again this is a ***guess*** based on the snippets provided.

Comment: @Nkosi I understand but I'm afraid I can't exactly share a full code snippet here. I agree that this is like to be a threading issue too, but the calling of the method happens for certain. Because I stepped through the code and saw it call and observed the `Callback()` and yet the exception was raised.

Comment: Full code is not needed. But enough for use to run and reproduce the problem. You are asking for help but if those trying to help have to do all the work to reproduce the problem you are less likely to get that help.

Comment: Also just because the method is called does not mean that it is called by the time the verification is done and or on the same thread. You see the issue there?

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah, that's fair enough. I added a bit more code that should allow you to reproduce it (basically get a few threads to set the value in dict to true for their thread id. I hope that will shed some light. I really appreciate you taking this time and effort to help me :)

Comment: @Nkosi Ha, that's an excellent point! I probably need a lock in the `Notify` method... Thank you. I'm not near the machine now but will certainly give that a try. Thanks for that idea.

Comment: @swdon here is suggestion. Try adding a delay between the Act and Assertion in the test to give the timer enough time to do its thing.

Comment: @Nkosi You are a star! Adding a little delay before verifying worked. Can you please add that as an answer, so I can accept? Thanks!

Comment: @swdon done. answer added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a threading issue or the timer might not have invoked by the time the verification was done. Which means that the mock members were not actually called yet when `Verify` was invoked.

You might have to wait a bit before verifying method call.

Try adding a delay between the Act and Assertion in the test to give the timer enough time to do its thing.

```
//Arrange

//...

//Act
// observable is the SUT.
var unsubscriber = observable.Subscribe(mock.Object);
// Cause OnCompleted() to be called: I verified that there's one observer in the observers list in observable and that my break point is correctly hit.

await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)); //Or some known duration

//Assert    
mock.Verify(v => v.OnCompleted(), Times.AtLeastOnce);
unsubscriber.Dispose();
```

Comment: It was the delay that worked for me thanks :)